# Dataframes in Python - matching multiple columns of rows between two data frames

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 - which holds a 'grouped inventory' of items grouped by numerical values A, B and C. For each item there is a sum column which should reflect the total price of all the items I have of that particular type. Initially I have set the sum column to zero.

df2 is a list of items I have with A, B, C and the price of the item.

df1 (Initial Inventory):

```
A     B     C   SUM
1     1     1    0
1     1     2    0
1     2     2    0
2     2     2    0
```

df2 (List of items):

```
A     B     C   PRICE
2     2     2    30
1     1     2    100
1     1     2    110
1     1     2    105
```

So my code should convert df1 into:

df1 (**expected output**):

```
A     B     C   SUM
1     1     1    0
1     1     2    315
1     2     2    0
2     2     2    30
```

**Explanation:** My list of items (df2) contains one item coded as 2,2,2 which has a value of 30 and contains three items coded as 1,1,2 which has values of 100 + 110 + 105 = 315. So I update the inventory table df1, to reflect that I have a total value of 30 for items coded 2,2,2 and total value of 315 for items coded 1,1,2. I have 0 in value for items coded 1,1,1 and 1,2,2 - since they aren't found in my items list.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I would rather not use loops since df1 is 720 rows and df2 is 10,000 rows.

Comment: can you explain more on how did you come up with the result?

Comment: @Tai Sure. My list of items (df2) contains one item coded as 2,2,2 which has a value of 30 and contains three items coded as 1,1,2 which has values of 100 + 110 + 105 = 315. So I update the inventory table df1, to reflect that I have a total value of 30 for items coded 2,2,2 and total value of 315 for items coded 1,1,2. I have 0 in value for items coded 1,1,1 and 1,2,2 - since they aren't found in my items list.

Comment: Please supply additional information by editing your question. People tend not to read comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `merge` on columns "A", "B", and "C" with `how="left"`. (`df2_sum` below is a subset of `df1`, so we choose `left` here.)

```
df2_sum = df2.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])["PRICE"].sum().reset_index()

df1.merge(df2_sum, on=["A","B","C"], how="left").fillna(0)
    A   B   C   SUM PRICE
0   1   1   1   0   0.0
1   1   1   2   0   315.0
2   1   2   2   0   0.0
3   2   2   2   0   30.0
```

You can then add `PRICE` to your `SUM` column.